# Commodore 64 Game with Falling Character Scream

Tags: commodore-64, identify-this-game

I'm trying to remember the name of a Commodore 64 game that had a character in it that would scream when it fell. I found videos of Impossible Mission, but the name doesn't seem right and the sound isn't the same as what I remember.

Comment: A 'realistic' character similar to that in Impossible Mission, or something more cartoony?

Comment: @Tommy: I think it was a similar type of character.

Comment: ISTR Nexus/Nexor had something along those lines, but drawing a blank on finding it

Comment: Do you remember anything else about this game?

Comment: @wizzwizz4: I think the character was a little man that ran around and there may have been elevators.

Comment: I think the sounds of the C64 were definitely better than most videos portray. As far as platforms and screams this seems like Impossible Mission to me- I remember it well. “Ah... another visitor - stay awhile... stay forever! [evil laugh]”.

Answer (score 4):

RE:

> I think it was a similar type of character

Impossible Mission II:

I found this youtube clip that contains the scream audio (the link should take you right to the point it occurs):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p3-yRum-eFg#t=1m14s

Answer (score 3):

A few possibilities:

- Rick Dangerous
- Kane
- The Way of the Exploding Fist

Comment: I came here to say Rick Dangerous. My friend had this on the Atari ST too.

Answer (score 2):

Beach Head also had that scream. I believe it was the same one used in Impossible Mission 1 and 2.

Comment: Awww!  I'm hit!!

Comment: Hey! Don't shoot me!